# Logic of average rating system not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to calculate the average of individual 1-5 ratings. I have tried to do this by saving the total number of comments to a variable `$no_of_comments = get_comments_number( $post_id );` Than I calculate the total ratings in a for loop

```
for ($i=get_comments_number(0); $i <= $no_of_comments; $i++) { 
    $tot_stars +=  get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true );
}
```

and then calculate the average rating `$avg_rating = ($tot_stars / $no_of_comments);`
Finally I set out to display my ratings

```
echo '<p id="avg-contain">';
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
                if ( $i <= $avg_rating ) {
                    echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/icon.png' ) . '" />';
                } else {
                    echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/grey.png' ). '" />';
                }
            }
echo '</p>';
```

I am unsure why this yields all grey stars, I have set up my individual ratings using the same `echo` logic, so it must be a logic error in my PHP above. Perhaps the `$avg_rating` is not a whole number?

Comment: changed `if ( $i <= $avg_rating ) {` to `if ( $i <= round($avg_rating) ) {` and was still ineffective, so the whole number issue was not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment loop uses what appears to be faulty logic.  You're just iterating from `get_comments_number( 0 )` to `$no_of_comments`, but you're not actually getting your individual comments anywhere.

Do this instead:

```
$args = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'status' => 'approve',
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) { 
    $tot_stars +=  get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
}
```

#### References

- [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Comment: I have adapted my code with what you have put above. I then added `$no_of_comments = get_comments_number( $post_id );` and `$avg_rating = ($tot_stars / $no_of_comments);` to display the `$avg_rating` below. This unfortunately is still not showing any icon stars, just grey stars.

Comment: I've fixed my code (the field is comment_ID, not comment_id). If it *still* doesn't work, try adding `echo $tot_stars;` after the end of the `foreach()` loop.